# How to scale and crop a sine wave in python and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math

I'm trying to generate a sine wave that matches my requirements for amplitude, number of phases and start and end values.

I can accurately control amplitude and number of phases, but I don't know how to set the start and end values accurately. I believe there is a mathematical approach to this, but I don't know where to start.

I also tried actually "cropping" the wave by cutting elements of `y` before start and after end, but beside being not very elegant, I encountered issues with accuracy.

Thanks for any help!

```
    import numpy as np
    import math
    import matplotlib.pylab as plt
    
    min=0
    max=180
    f = 2
    start = 45
    stop = 60
    
    t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
    
    y = ((max+min)/2) + (((max-min)/2) * np.sin(f*t + 100)) # "100" set manually by experimenting 
    
    actual_min, actual_max = np.min(y), np.max(y)
    actual_start, actual_stop = y[0], y[-1]
    
    print(f"min: {actual_min}, max: {actual_max}")
    print(f"start: {actual_start}, stop: {actual_stop}")
    
    plt.plot(t, y)
```

```
min: 0.00019246157938823671, max: 179.99994783571566
start: 44.42709230012171, stop: 44.42709230012167
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`arcsin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arcsin.html) to get the `t` for a given `y`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

min = 0
max = 180
f = 2
start = 45
stop = 60

a = (max + min) / 2
b = (max - min) / 2
t0 = np.arcsin((start - a) / b) / f
t1 = np.arcsin((stop - a) / b) / f + 2 * np.pi

t = np.linspace(t0, t1, 1000)
y = a + b * np.sin(f * t)

assert np.allclose([start, stop], [y[0], y[-1]])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How would you update the function so it’s possible to decide if the start point and stop value are on the respective up slope or down slope? I’m guessing I would need to shift left or right by half a phase but I’m not sure how to go about it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you - just compare the y value for the start/end point with the next/previous y value and you see if the function goes up or down?

Comment: I could do what you suggest to verify where my start is, and then update the formula and run again,  but it’s a 2-step process and I would avoid that if possible. What I would like to do is to tune the formula so that the wave is already shifted so that the start and end slopes are going in the direction I need.

Comment: Well, the start will always be on an up slope as the `arcsin` convention is to return the angle between -pi/2 and +pi/2. If you need the start to be on the down slope, you can adjust it `t0 = np.pi / f - t0`. Analogously for the end.